# Facebook sharer not sharing the proper image and content

Tags: laravel, facebook, share

I am trying to share the product url using facebook sharer and the link is also sharing properly but the problem is that while sharing, it didn't sharing the product image. Its sharing some other random image from the page, I don't understand why its happening. Also, while sharing contents contain the html tags.
Here is my sharer url :

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ urlencode(route('product.link', ['id' => $productdetails->ref_id])) }}" class="social-share-btn" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Facebook" style="font-size:20px" ><img src="{{url('/')}}/asset/social/fb.png" style="width: 40px; margin-right: 7px;"></a>
```

Here is my image while sharing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeXcW.png)

I have also added the line in `<head></head>` i.e.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```

but not useful.

Please help me out, I am poorly trapped in it.

Comment: Step one: Put the URL through the Facebook debug tool, and see what that has to say.

Comment: Html tags are removed now but the image problem is still there

Comment: Well my browser can’t load `http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg` either, gets a 403 - is that supposed to be the actual URL, or did you “anonymize” that?

Comment: I have tried with actual url but still the same issue

Comment: Then the debug tool probably got some error messages for you, relating to that. We need some details here, not just repeatedly the word “issue”, that tells rather little.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the following line

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```

And debug in [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). if it doesn't show the correct image, click Scrape again button.

Also, something is wrong in your og:description. That's why its showing the code

Comment: I have already added this line, you can see in my question section but its not working

Comment: @Bhawesh just repeatedly stating “not working”, is not actually helpful. Please add some details to your question, that help us see what the problem actually is.

Comment: I have got the solution and its working fine, thank you for the support